# How do I make a direct call to ReactiveCommand.Execute() in ReactiveUI 7 correct?

Tags: c#, reactiveui

I'm trying to convert my project from ReactiveUI 6.5 to version 7. In the old version I called

```
// var command = ReactiveCommand.Create...;
// ...
if(command.CanExecute(null))
    command.Execute(null);
```

in order to execute a command from my code behind.

Now the CanExecute method is no longer available and replaced with a property of `IObservable<bool>`. Is the CanExecute Observable automatically called if I just make a call to `Execute().Subscribe()` or must I call it explicitly?

For now I replaced the above code with

```
command.Execute().Subscribe();
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found three different solutions to call my command's `CanExecute` and `Execute` methods like I could before in ReactiveUI 6.5:

**Option 1**

This  is equal to the call in version 6.5, but we need to explicitly convert the command to an ICommand:

```
if (((ICommand) command).CanExecute(null))
    command.Execute().Subscribe();
```

**Option 2**

```
if(command.CanExecute.FirstAsync().Wait())
    command.Execute().Subscribe()
```

or the async variant:

```
if(await command.CanExecute.FirstAsync())
    await command.Execute()
```

**Option 3**

Another option is to make us of the `InvokeCommand` extension method.

```
Observable.Start(() => {}).InvokeCommand(ViewModel, vm => vm.MyCommand);
```

This respects the command's executability, like mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.reactiveui.net/en/user-guide/commands/invoking-commands.html).

---

In order to make it more comfortable I've written a small extension method to provide a `ExecuteIfPossible` and a `GetCanExecute` method:

```
public static class ReactiveUiExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<bool> ExecuteIfPossible<TParam, TResult>(this ReactiveCommand<TParam, TResult> cmd) =>
        cmd.CanExecute.FirstAsync().Where(can => can).Do(async _ => await cmd.Execute());

    public static bool GetCanExecute<TParam, TResult>(this ReactiveCommand<TParam, TResult> cmd) =>
        cmd.CanExecute.FirstAsync().Wait();
}
```

You can use this extension method as follows:

```
command.ExecuteIfPossible().Subscribe();
```

Note: You need the `Subscribe()` call at the end, just like you need it for the call to `Execute()`, otherwise nothing will happen.

Or if you want to use async and await:

```
await command.ExecuteIfPossible();
```

If you want to check if a command can be executed, just call

```
command.GetCanExecute()
```

Comment: Thanks for figuring out work arounds for CanExecute(null) when upgrading from 6.5.